# Getting attributes from xml using Linq

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I have an xml document that I want to obtain attributes from

Here is the XML:

```
<Translations>
   <Product Name="Room" ID="16">
      <Terms>
         <Term Generic="Brand" Product="Sub Category" />
         <Term Generic="Range" Product="Brand" />
      </Terms>
   </Product>
   <Product Name="House"" ID="29">
      <Terms>
          <Term Generic="Category" Product="Product Brand" />
          <Term Generic="Brand" Product="Category Description" />
          <Term Generic="Range" Product="Group Description" />
          <Term Generic="Product" Product="Product Description" />
      </Terms>
   </Product>
</Translations>
```

Here is my current Linq query

```
public static string clsTranslationTesting(string GenericTerm, int ProductID)
{
    const string xmlFilePath = "C:\\Dev\\XMLTrial\\XMLFile1.xml";
    var xmlDocument =  XDocument.Load(xmlFilePath);
    var genericValue =
        from gen in xmlDocument.Descendants("Product")
        where gen.Attribute("ID").Value == ProductID.ToString()
        select gen.Value.ToString();
}
```

The error that I am having is when I pass data into the method, the method loads the xml from the file to the xmlDocument variable successfully. However when it executes the query it returns a value null. I want to obtain the ID value.

Comment: Maybe its just me but I dont see `Customer` anywhere in your XML...

Comment: Yes, I guess should be `Product` instead of `Customer`

Comment: Change From : gen.Value.ToString(); To : gen.Value;

Comment: Why would you want to *obtain* the `ID` attribute when you're already filtering on that? Surely it's going to be the same as `ProductID` everywhere... (Now would be a good time to learn and follow .NET naming conventions, btw.) I suggest you clarify your question - and change your example into a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little lost with your question, but here's my attempt.

First thing is you need to change "Customer" to "Product".  Your XML contains not a single instance of the word "Customer" so I think you have a typo there.

I don't know exactly what you want returned from the query (I assume just the entire matched node?).  Try this:

```
var genericValue = xmlDocument.Descendants("Product")
                       .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Attribute("ID").Value == "16");
```

I made a fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Otmaa6) that shows it in action